# Directory Not Found Error

Tags: ubuntu, tails

I am trying to verify tails and when I get to the command prompt portion of the verification some difficulties seem to have arose. Below is the script:

```
noob@noob-System-Product-Name:~$ cd [/media/noob/UUI]
bash: cd: [/media/noob/UUI]: No such file or directory 

noob@noob-System-Product-Name:~$ gpg --keyid-format long --import tails-signing.key
gpg: can't open `tails-signing.key': No such file or directory gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Same thing happens when I try from download directory;

```
noob@noob-System-Product-Name:~$ cd [/home/noob/Downloads] 
bash: cd: [/home/noob/Downloads]: No such file or directory 

noob@noob-System-Product-Name:~$ gpg --keyid-format long --import tails-signing.key 
gpg: can't open `tails-signing.key': No such file or directory gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll notice the `No such file or directory` error from your attempt to `cd`. You're running that command incorrectly (namely, you're putting brackets around your paths for some reason).

Answer (score 1):

You have brackets in your path.

This is correct:

```
cd /media/noob/UUI
```

This is not correct:

```
cd [/media/noob/UUI]
```